# How to receive an incoming message in Socket Programming iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets

I'm developing an App where I'm able to send/recieve messages to/from PHP server using socket, I'm referring  [Ray's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) for Socket programming.

But now I want to send to send messages to another user who is using the App, I have his IP Address and Port no, So I can send message to the user but How will that user recieve the message, because he not connected to my port. How will he notify that there is an incoming message for him?

I'm doing socket programming for very first time.

Comment: it means chatting only ryt?